# springcloud api gateway properties file declaring variables

Tags: java, microservices, properties-file, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

I have application.yaml in springboot app as below

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: pgService
        uri: http://localhost:2005/
        predicates:
        - Path=/employee/**
      - id: inMateService
        uri: http://localhost:2006/
        predicates:
        - Path=/consumer/**
```

The above declared variables are with respect to spring cloud gateway

I want to declare these same variables in application.properties file.
i don't want to use yaml file. please help me to achieve this
Thank you

Answer (score 12):

You can define the variables as follows in your `application.properties` file:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=pgService
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=http://localhost:2005/
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/employee/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=inMateService
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=http://localhost:2006/
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/consumer/**
```

Answer (score 3):

Just updated the ans.

It should be similer to this format:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.predicates[0].name: Path
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.predicates[0].args[pattern]: "'/'+serviceId+'/**'"
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.predicates[1].name: Host
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.predicates[1].args[pattern]: "'**.foo.com'"
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.filters[0].name: Hystrix
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.filters[0].args[name]: serviceId
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.filters[1].name: RewritePath
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.filters[1].args[regexp]: "'/' + serviceId + '/(?<remaining>.*)'"
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.filters[1].args[replacement]: "'/${remaining}'"
```

Ref. https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/multi/multi__configuration.html

---

If you are using intelliJ, the below plugin is so helpful for converting the format between .yaml and .properties:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13804-convert-yaml-and-properties-file

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me

---

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=USER-SERVICE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://USER-SERVICE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0].name=Path
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0].args[pattern]=/user/**

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=USER-SERVICE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=lb://USER-SERVICE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0].name=Path
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0].args[pattern]=/department/**
```

Comment: U can change the id and uri in second declaration.

Answer (score 1):

### works for me

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=USER-SERVICE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://USER-SERVICE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/v1/users/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=DEPARTMENT-SERVICE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=lb://DEPARTMENT-SERVICE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/v1/departments/**
```

In my cotroller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/users")
public class UserController {


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/departments")
```

You need to change them

Answer (score 0):

```
## microservices mapping ##
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=product-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://product-service
#spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=http://localhost:8002/
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/product/api/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=StripPrefix=2

## microservices mapping ##
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=product-service
#spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=lb://product-serviceed
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=http://localhost:8003
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/user/api/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].filters[0]=StripPrefix=2

Please refer code here : https://github.com/sunilkul/spring-cloud- 
microservice/tree/spring-cloud-demo
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).